# How to trigger selectbox change event from selectbox.js

Tags: drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I am using [Selectbox.js](http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/) and it's transformation an existing select box to `<dl>...<dd></dd></dl>` tags.

Now problem is my existing select box was executing such `onchange` event but after transformation it's not working. Existing select box is getting hidden and new look is being displayed but functionality of existing select box has been stopped.

I have initialized it like below

```
$("select").each(function() {
    var selectBox = new SelectBox({
    selectbox: $(this),
    height: 140,
    width: "100%"
    });
});
```

How can I keep my existing bound functionality on select box after transformation?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging through out Selectbox.js file I found solution to call selecbox's `change()` in Selectbox's `changeCallback` method. Default it's empty. So we just have to replace existing `changeCallback` line with below one. This line exists on 53

```
changeCallback: function(val) { options.selectbox.change(); },
```